# Long delay in DNS lookup after restart/resume windows

Tags: windows-7, dns, delay, request-timed-out

Since I've a new Cisco router I've trouble browsing the web after resuming or starting my laptop. I did some debugging and it seems that I have a network connection, but that the DNS is failing for a while (say; more that 50 seconds).

You can see what I mean in my **ping** and **nslookup** output below.
I tried this with Google Nameservers and my internet providers' DNS server, but both have the same result. After everything is fired-up for a while, everything works fine. (meaning, internet works, and all tried nameservers reply really fast).

Would be nice if someone has a clue on how to solve this issue.

Extra info: windows7, broadband connection, both wifi and cable connections share this problem.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 21ms, Average = 18ms

C:\Windows\system32>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

> www.google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
> www.google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
> www.google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
> www.google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

--------8<------after a while---------

C:\Windows\system32>ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=54
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=54

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 21ms, Average = 18ms

C:\Windows\system32>nslookup
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Default Server:  [8.8.8.8]
Address:  8.8.8.8

> www.google.com
Server:  [8.8.8.8]
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.l.google.com
Addresses:  173.194.66.99
          173.194.66.106
          173.194.66.147
          173.194.66.103
          173.194.66.104
          173.194.66.105
Aliases:  www.google.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. Here's what worked for me, behind a Cisco EPC3925 (cable ISP).

In Windows 7/8 open Network and Sharing Center > Manage Adapter Settings. You may need to hold down the ALT button to see the Advanced > Advanced Settings Options .
In adapters and bindings, check that the bindings list TCP/IPv4 *before* TCP/IPv6

Comment: there is not this option in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

G'Day.
I've had a similar problem with the Cisco EPC-3925 for many years, at one time I even experimented with IPv4 & 6 settings (to no avail). I found that the longer I left the router running, the longer the pings were, and the slower my internet connectioin.

Here's a test you can try:
Reboot 3925 and get your results from speedtest.net (mine are near 120Mbps after a reboot).
Without rebooting the router, try speedtest again after 12 hours, then 24 hours, 48, 72 etc. (You can test more often, but the results won't be as great).
Record all your speedtest values, and see if your router is slowing down over time. Rumor has it the Network Address Translation Table (NAT) is somehow getting corrupted, but any suggestions I found to fix that problem also failed (for me).

I tried all sorts of things to fix it, in the end I used a power socket timer in the wall, with the router plugged into it. The timer reboots the router at 3:30am every day - which solves the problem for me. It's crude, but effective. Doesn't solve the underlying problem, but sidesteps instead.

The same thing MAY work for you... TEST by forcing your PC to sleep, wake it, then run the above test to see what happens.

Just an idea, but may work for you.

There may of course be other issues... e.g. Are you using a wireless connection to the router - is there any interference on the WIFI channel etc etc.

Regards, Greg.